# TYPO3 Fluid Form - The given string was not appended with a valid HMAC

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I tried to change a Fluid Form from POST to GET, when i ran into this error:

[The given string was not appended with a valid HMAC.](https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1320830018)

The form is completely created with Fluid (`f:form, f:form.select, f:form.submit`) and there are no additional changes after creation.

I have a DEV Server with a copy but the error is not present there. The Form has the exact same values for all of my and the hidden-fields (`__referrer-Array` and `__trustedProperties`).
This means the HMAC string (at the end of this parameters) is the same.

`TYPO3 6.2.27`

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit for URLs and it is about 2000 characters ([What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)). If this limit is reached than the rest should be truncated resulting in missing variables. Either the hmac variable is at the end and is not passed to your server or other variables that are used in the HMAC calculation are missing resulting in a wrong hmac. This, however, should only be the case for large forms.

PS: the referrer field can be large to huge especially if you used `$this->forward` with model objects in the arguments array

Comment: Unfortunetly this is not the problem. The DEV System has the same URL lenght (about 950 chars). It's a very short form with only 3 fields (searchfilter)

Comment: This could be a stupid question, but did you clean the cache?

Comment: In TYPO3 this is never a stupid question ;-) - i did :-(